# Grails security filter all action but except one

Tags: security, grails, groovy, grails-filters

I'm gonna create a security filter for my project. I check `if !session.user then redirect to action error`.
Here is my current code:

```
all(controller: 'accounting|installation|installer|sales|service|serviceOrder|document', action: '*') {
            before = {
                if (!session.user) {
                    redirect(controller: 'installation', action: 'errors')
                    return false
                }
            }
            after = { Map model ->

            }
            afterView = { Exception e ->

            }
        }
```

However the point is that `session.user` being created in `controller 'installation'` and `action 'index'`. So how can I filter without `index action`?
Any suggestions  will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you want the check `if(!session.user){...}`  on all controller's action except for `index`action of `installation` controller??

Comment: Yes, that's all I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
all(controller: 'accounting|installation|installer|sales|service|serviceOrder|document', action: '*') {
        before = {
         if (!(controllerName == 'installation' && actionName == 'index')) {
            if (!session.user) {
                redirect(controller: 'installation', action: 'errors')
                return false
            }
          }
        }
        after = { Map model ->

        }
        afterView = { Exception e ->

        }
    }
```

Comment: Guys,I tried your solution and get this message: `Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

    This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.
`

Comment: try to enable cookies in your browser : https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/enable-and-disable-cookies-website-preferences

Answer (score 4):

You can use `invert:true`
e.g

```
def filters = {
    allExceptIndex(controller:"installation",action:"index",invert:true) {
        before = {
        }
        after = { Map model ->
        }
        afterView = { Exception e ->
        }
    }
}
```

For further reference see [Blog](http://www.jellyfishtechnologies.com/invocation-sequence-grails-filters/)

Answer (score 0):

Hope I have understood your question ,Since you want to exclude action index then ,try this ..

```
all(controller: 'accounting|installation|installer|sales|service|serviceOrder|document', action: '*',actionExclude:'index'){....
```

Regards

Comment: Guys,I tried your solution and get this message: `Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

    This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.
`

Comment: 1. Enable cookie. 2."Clear the Cache":
Tools > Options > Advanced > Network > Cached Web Content: "Clear Now" 3.Also try in other browser. This can be caused by corrupted cookies or cookies that aren't send or otherwise blocked.

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Cookies